# Integer overflow/underflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I am learning about integer overflows and underflows and was wondering if it is it possible to control the value of j by giving a negative input n?

```
int i = n;
size_t j = i;
printf("%lu",j);
```

for example, if I want the value of "j" to be 255, is it possible to craft the negative number "n" to give me that output?

Comment: Yes it is! You can set `n` to 255. :-P

Comment: There's no such thing is "integer underflow", In the generally accepted nomenclature, "underflow" can only happen in floating-point arithmetic. As your your question, the answer is simple: just set your `n` to `255`. The simplicity and triviality of the answer makes one suspect that you missed something in your question.

Comment: i'm sorry, i meant by giving negative value. i have updated the question

Comment: What is the type of `n`? Anyway, it is not possible to answer the question about negative value of `n` without knowing the exact characteristics of  `size_t` type (its range, specifically). It is platform-dependent. And you should use `%zu` to print `size_t` values, not `%lu`.

Comment: "n" is of type int, and size_t is usually unsigned long I think.

Comment: Firstly, "usually" is not good enough. Secondly, it does not help at all since the range of `unsigned long` is still implementation-dependent, which makes your question impossible to answer without exploring all possible combinations.

Comment: If you cast a variable containing `-1` to an `uint8_t`, you'll get `255`. However, `255` is less than `0x8000`, so I don't think you'll be able to get it by casting a negative to any integer type larger than 8 bits. And needless to say, I don't think you're going to find any modern platforms (or ancient ones, for that matter) on which `unsigned long` is only 8 bits in size.

Comment: @Charles Srstka: On a weird imaginary platform with 64-bit `int` and 32-bit `size_t` it would be perfectly possible. Setting `i` to `-9223372036854775553` would result in `255` in `j`. But true, if `int` is not wider than `size_t` then negative value in `i` will never produce `255` in `j`.

Comment: @AnT Ah, you are correct. However, I would be quite shocked indeed to see any platform in which `int` was larger than `size_t`.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka `unsigned long` must be at least 32 bits

Comment: @M.M You don't say!

Comment: What is `underflow`? Kindly remove all `underflow` words from your title and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
signed char i = -1;
unsigned char j = i;
printf("%u\n", j);
```

In 8 bits, the signed number -1 "wraps around" to the unsigned value 255.

You asked about `size_t` because, yes, it's an unsigned type, but it's typically 32 or even 64 bits.  At those sizes, the number 255 is representable (and has the same representation) in both the signed and unsigned variants, so there isn't a negative number that corresponds to 255.  But you can certainly see similar effects, using different values.  For example, on a machine with 32-bit ints, this code:

```
unsigned int i = 4294967041;
int j = i;
printf("%d\n", j);
```

is likely to print -255.  This value comes about because 2^32 - 255 = 4294967041.

Comment: In the latter code, the behaviour is implementation-defined (and may raise a signal)